# Combining date and time into datetime

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to merge date & time. I have used 'CONCAT' function & also '||' function. But both of functions taking more times and very slow for query. Can somebody tell me how i can reduce the query time? & What function can be used to merge the date & time? Thanks for any help.

```
    where CONCAT (TO_CHAR (Date, 'YYYYMMDD'), LPAD (Time, 6, 0))
between CONCAT ('20180215', '130528') AND CONCAT ('20180215', '133003')
```

Comment: What are DATE and TIME datatypes?  DATE looks like a DATE (as you wrote TO_CHAR against it); is it truncated so that it doesn't contain time component so you're then concatenating it with TIME? BTW, why are you concatenating values you use in BETWEEN? Those are pure strings, use them as '20180215130528', without concatenation. Anyway: if you post table description, it might be easier to answer.

Comment: @Littlefoot, Date & Time totally separate column. Datatype "Date" for DATE and datatype "NUMBER(38)" for Time. I used concatenation for between coz, here date & time is not fixed. For example i have just given.

Comment: @Littlefoot has a point, if you can at some point, fix your data model, just use date to store your data, then no special sql tricks necessary to get what you want

Comment: `DATE` already includes a time in Oracle. Why are you storing the time redundantly in a second column?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to convert your date to a string - just convert your static values to a date:

```
WHERE "Date" BETWEEN TO_DATE( '20180215130528', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
                 AND TO_DATE( '20180215133003', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
```

If you want to use `CONCAT` then:

```
WHERE "Date" BETWEEN TO_DATE( CONCAT( '20180215', '130528' ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
                 AND TO_DATE( CONCAT( '20180215', '133003' ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
```

You could also use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```
WHERE "Date" BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2018-02-15 13:05:28'
                 AND TIMESTAMP '2018-02-15 13:30:03'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an index on Date to speed up the query.
And better yet would be to have Date and Time combined into a single field Date, with type Date (and have index on Date). 
This would give you a simple performant query:

```
WHERE Date between to_date('20180215' || '130528', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') and to_date('20180215'||'133003', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

For your current scheme, you will get better performance structuring WHERE like this:

```
where Date between to_date('20180215', 'YYYYMMDD') and to_date('20180215', 'YYYYMMDD') and Date || LPAD (Time, 6, 0)) between CONCAT ('20180215', '130528') AND CONCAT ('20180215', '133003')
```

Comment: You should not advise people to add an index to a column without knowing much more about their scenario. We haven't even seen the whole query, let alone an explain plan.

Comment: But I'm not urging the author to add an index, I just want them to make sure they have one.

Comment: Hmmm, I interpreted *"you want to have an index"* to mean you were advising them to have an index on the column. Silly me.